# snowflake concat two fields with space

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got two fields: First_name (e.g.John) and Surname (e.g.Doe)
How do I concat these for a join to another table that's Name (e.g. John Doe).
Trying contact(First_name, Surname) gives me JohnDoe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cases where you will only have two fields, there are three equally trivial methods, [CONCAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html), [||](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat.html), & [CONCAT_WS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat_ws.html):

```
select 
    first_name
    ,surname
    ,concat(first_name, ' ', surname) as way1
    ,first_name || ' ' || surname as way2
    ,concat_ws(' ',first_name, surname) as way3
from values
    ('john', 'doe'),
    ('the rock', null) 
    as t(first_name, surname);
```

| FIRST_NAME | SURNAME | WAY1 | WAY2 | WAY3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | john doe | john doe | john doe |
| the rock | null | null | null | null |

but if any of those tokens are null, then the whole things is null.

If you have more than 2 tokens and non are null, then concat_ws starts to win.

and if you want something that can handle nulls but not have unwanted whitespace. you need to use [array_construct_compact](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_construct_compact.html)/[array_to_string](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_to_string.html):

```
select 
    one
    ,two
    ,three
    ,concat(one, ' ', two, ' ', three) as way1
    ,one || ' ' || two || ' ' || three as way2
    ,concat_ws(' ',one, two, three) as way3
    ,array_to_string(array_construct_compact(one, two, three), ' ') as way4
from values
    ('john', 'doe', ''),
    ('the rock', null, null),
    ('three','happy', 'words')
    as t(one, two, three);
```

| ONE | TWO | THREE | WAY1 | WAY2 | WAY3 | WAY4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john | doe | '' | john doe | john doe | john doe | john doe |
| the rock | null | null | null | null | null | the rock |
| three | happy | words | three happy words | three happy words | three happy words | three happy words |

Answer (score 2):

There looks to be a concat with separator function https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/concat_ws.html

Try `concat_ws(' ', First_name, Surname);`